# Can't run Meteor mobile app (GETs failed)

Tags: mobile, meteor

I spent 3 days trying to connect my Meteor mobile app to existing server. It is working well on server and I want to build app with:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server=https://domain.com:443
```

I tried to do various enviromental variables for `ROOT_URL`, for example:

```
ROOT_URL='https://domain.com'
ROOT_URL='https://domain.com:443'
ROOT_URL='https://ip:443' etc.
```

In any configuration I have problems with GETs. They are canceled or failed. When I set mobile-server to `http://domain.com:80` there is error:

> WebSocket connection to ws://domain.com/sockjs/363/ruuwxpal/websocket
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   400

When I set mobile-server to `https://domain.com:443` it refuses all GET requests and `Meteor.status` I jumping between connecting and waiting.

Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you check the connection. Maybe the request does not even get to the server.

Comment: Might be worth deploying to Meteor's free hosting (meteor deploy appname) and setting that as your mobile-server. If it works there you'll know there's something wrong with your hosting setup.